# 800,000 Products Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, simple-product

The client has 800 styles. But 1000 variations of each style since there is 4 attributes with alot of options.

So 800 configurable products with 1K simple products per configurable product so 800k products.

My concerns will be can Magento handle that and will there be some reindexing issues or any other issues?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Site: 1.9.2.2

Comment: going with `simple products with custom options` is one more option instead of `configurable products`, but you need to research more about adv and disadvantages of both

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea

We have just over 70K products and we drop the rewrite table and re-index numerous times per day and this process takes around 6 minutes to process so I assume that as yours is over 10X ours it will be significantly longer